# How to decode an embedded base64 string?

Tags: bash, base64

I want to decode an embedded base64 string.

- **input line:**
  `Subscriber,services,,1,dGVsOis0OTEyMzQ1NjcK`
- **expected output:**
  `Subscriber,services,,1,tel:+491234567`

The base64 string itself is easily decoded with:

```
echo 'dGVsOis0OTEyMzQ1NjcK' | base64 -d
```

How can I decode an embedded base64 string?

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: How can i decode an embedded bas64 string?

Comment: It's not going to work... `Subscriber` and `services` are technically a base64 string. You can try to decode all the fields by splitting with `,` but you will have a very bogus output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to receive the second line from the first line, then it should be like this:

```
MYSTRING="Subscriber,services,,1,dGVsOis0OTEyMzQ1NjcK"
RESULT="${MYSTRING%,*},$( base64 -d <<< ${MYSTRING##*,} )"
echo $RESULT
# Will print "Subscriber,services,,1,tel:+491234567"
```

If you need to do this for different records where encoded field is located in different positions, then it will be more complicated